# Enviar log de usuario a una tabla mediante un boton en php

Tags: php, javascript

Buen día!

Tengo un botón en php de la siguiente forma

```
echo CHtml::button(Yii::t('site', 'Help (F2)'), array('id' => 'run_example'));
```

El cual ejecuta una funcion de js de la siguiente manera

```
$("#run_example").click(function(){
     Sideshow.start({ listAll: true });
   });
```

Quiero que cuando algun usuario haga clic en ese boton se envie la informacion como nombre de usuario, hora, fecha a una tabla MySQL

Espero haberme explicado bien y me puedan ayudar.

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer una accion en tu controladora desde la cual accedas a travez de un POST y en el cuerpo de la misma invokes una consulta donde guardes los datos que deseas. Y llamar a un $.post al hacer click en el boton #run_example

Comment: Desde tu llamada javascript tendras que hacer una llamada ajax a un script de php (pasandole los valores necesarios) que será la que se grabe dichos datos a la BBDD.

Comment: Espero no molestar demasiado, me podrías apoyar con algún ejemplo de codigo?? espero no quitar mucho tiempo soy nuevo en php.